# How to make table cell separator to our desire view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

1. Hi i want to set a table cell seperator to the following fashion is there any coding to

   make this manually

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

You can, however, hide the cell separator and add the view you want at the bottom of each cell.

Comment: Ya i did it by adding a ui view with height 1 and black background color and added it as a cell content view

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using background image of cell. Make a image for cell with footer black line and hide the cell separator so it will look like above image.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cell separator style to none and add an image to the custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

set the section footer/header view as your desired separater view and set cell separater as none

Comment: is there any chance to make a line like that

Comment: yes, make an image like that, then in viewfor header/footer section method, make an imageview and set it's image the line, plus clear the imageview's background color

Answer (score 0):

in the following delegate method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [cell setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
   [cell addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImg.png"]]];
}
```